# Base64 embedded pdf working in chrome 12 but not in firefox 5

Tags: html, pdf, object, base64

I´m trying to embed a base64 encoded pdf within an html object:

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0..." type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

Same code works fine in chrome 12 but not in firefox 5. In firefox, reader plugin seems to be loaded ok, because I can see something like a loading progress bar. I´m using reader 10 plugin.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be a maximum data uri length?

Comment: I tried with a 10kb base64 pdf with same results.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is capable to render simple PDFs itself, it does not require Adobe Reader Plugin. You should check whether the Adobe Reader plugin is properly working in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You are right; chrome is using it´s own renderer. I was wrong because of the pdf toolbar, very similar to adobe one. I think adobe plugin is properly configured, because using urls instead base64 strings, it´s working fine.

Is there anything else to configure?

Disabling embedded plugin, Chrome acts if I´m downloading the file, opening after that the local pdf viewer.

Regards